# SQL Query Combine Table

Tags: sql

How to I combine 3 table together using the SQL below?

```
-----------   -----------   -----------
AdminAccLog   StaffAccLog   PublicAccLog
-----------   -----------   -----------
id            id            id
name          name          name
ipaddress     ipaddress     ipaddress
datetime      datetime      datetime
task          task          task
---------------------------------------
```

Data

```
AdminAccLog 1 ABC 127.0.0.1 30/7/2017 0:00:00AM Logon
AdminAccLog 2 ABC 127.0.0.1 30/7/2017 1:00:00AM Logon
AdminAccLog 3 ABC 127.0.0.1 31/7/2017 0:00:00AM Logon

StaffAccLog 1 ABC 127.0.0.1 31/7/2017 0:00:00AM Logon
PublicAccLog 1 ABC 127.0.0.1 31/7/2017 0:00:00AM Logon
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PublicCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS PublicDate 
FROM PublicAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS StaffCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS StaffDate 
FROM StaffAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS AdminCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS AdminDate 
FROM AdminAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)
```

I want the query result to be like this in a same table (not insert table)

New Query Result to be:

```
----------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
PublicCount PublicDate StaffCount StaffDate AdminCount AdminDate
----------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
 1          31/7/2017  1          31/7/2017 2          30/7/2017 0:00:00AM
                                            1          31/7/2017 0:00:00AM
```

Another example:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3E2l.jpg)

[I want the result to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6lAV.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As stated, this doesn't look like a sensible thing to do in SQL, because the columns on a single row are not related to each other.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the date column to be the same on each row and then just to get the count.

One method uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT dte, SUM(PublicCount) as PublicCount, SUM(StaffCount) as StaffCount,
       SUM(AdminCount) as AdminCount
FROM ((SELECT CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS dte , COUNT(*) AS PublicCount,
              0 as StaffCount, 0 as AdminCount
       FROM PublicAccLog
       WHERE task = 'Logon' 
       GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, datetime), 0, COUNT(*) AS StaffCount, 0 AS StaffDate 
       FROM StaffAccLog
       WHERE task = 'Logon' 
       GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, datetime), 0, 0, COUNT(*) AS AdminCount
       FROM AdminAccLog
       WHERE task = 'Logon' 
       GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime)
      )
     ) t
GROUP BY dte
ORDER BY dte;
```

Comment: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @Syy . . . These do -- now that I fixed the typo in the second subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
MAX(PublicCount)PublicCount,
MAX(PublicDate),
MAX(StaffCount)StaffCount,
MAX(StaffDate)StaffDate,
MAX(AdminCount)AdminCount,
MAX(AdminDate)AdminDate 
    from (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PublicCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS PublicDate 
FROM PublicAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime) )T
,
(

SELECT COUNT(*) AS StaffCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS StaffDate 
FROM StaffAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime))TT
,

(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AdminCount, CONVERT(DATE, datetime) AS AdminDate 
FROM AdminAccLog WHERE task = 'Logon' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, datetime) )TTT
```